# Express request is called twice

Tags: node.js, http, express

To learn node.js I'm creating a small app that get some rss feeds stored in mongoDB, process them and create a single feed (ordered by date) from these ones.

It parses a list of ~50 rss feeds, with ~1000 blog items, so it's quite long to parse the whole, so I put the following `req.connection.setTimeout(60*1000);` to get a long enough time out to fetch and parse all the feeds.

Everything runs quite fine, but the request is called twice. (I checked with wireshark, I don't think it's about favicon here).

I really don't get it.

You can test yourself here : http://mighty-springs-9162.herokuapp.com/feed/mde/20 (it should create a rss feed with the last 20 articles about "mde").

The code is here: https://github.com/xseignard/rss-unify

And if we focus on the interesting bits :

I have a route defined like this : `app.get('/feed/:name/:size?', topics.getFeed);`

And the `topics.getFeed` is like this :

```
function getFeed(req, res) {
  // 1 minute timeout to get enough time for the request to be processed
  req.connection.setTimeout(60*1000);   

  var name = req.params.name;
  var callback = function(err, topic) {
  // if the topic has been found
  if (topic) {
    // aggregate the corresponding feeds
    rssAggregator.aggregate(topic, function(err, rssFeed) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({error: 'Error while creating feed'});
      }
      else {
        res.send(rssFeed);
      }
    },
    req);
  }
  else {
    res.status(404).send({error: 'Topic not found'});
  }};
  // look for the topic in the db
  findTopicByName(name, callback);
}
```

So nothing fancy, but still, this getFeed function is called twice.

What's wrong there? Any idea?

Comment: Most common problem is that somewhere you forgot to use `return`

Comment: Hello mvbl-fst, I don't get what you mean by forgetting ```return```. Can you explain more?

Comment: I might be wrong about the above and in this code nothing stands out to make it execute twice (except favicon.ico but you said it's out of the question). The only thing I would do is do `return findTopicByName(name, callback);`. But pretty sure it won't help.

Comment: I tried your tip, but with no luck. I really can't figure what's the problem...

Comment: can you add it to git so I can pull and see what's going on?

Comment: thanks for your patience 'mvbl fst', here is the repo: https://github.com/xseignard/rss-unify

I commited your ```return``` idea.
To get things running localy, you need a mongodb running on ```localhost:27017``` with a db called 'topicsDB', and then you can go in the utils folder and do a ```node populateDB.js``` to put some data in the db.
Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: So I made some more investigations, and it seems to only happen with Chromium (and Chrome I presume), with firefox it does not occurs.

Comment: Do you see what requests it is making in Network panel?

Comment: try using req.connection.timeout() method. https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2512

Answer (score 10):

This annoyed me for a long time. It's most likely the Firebug extension which is sending a duplicate of each GET request in the background. Try turning off Firebug to make sure that's not the issue.

Comment: This was the issue in my case, too. GET request to http://localhost:3000/tracks was called once, GET request to http://localhost:3000/tracks/post was called twice. When I turned off Firebug (in Chrome), the second request was called once, too.

Comment: This happened to me too, but with the chrome dev tools. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why.

Comment: I have the same issue and it is definitely not firebug. It's somehow related to a request respond time in my case, because my request that is called twice performs a lot of computing and send response after 3-4 minutes. And second request is not occuring if I just respond fast with no computings involved.

Comment: I also have to notice that my request is not GET request, it's POST request that's called twice.

Comment: @user619271 in your case is a timeout issue. Nodejs has by default 2 minutes. You can tune this in general or by request.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue while using [Google Cloud Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) (which uses `express` to handle requests) on my local machine. Each `fetch` request (in browser console and within web page) made resulted in two requests to the server. The issue was related to CORS (because I was using different ports), Chrome made a `OPTIONS` method call before the actual call. Since `OPTIONS` method was not necessary in my code, I used an if-statement to return an empty response.

```
if(req.method == "OPTIONS"){
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.status(204).send('');
}
```

Spent nearly 3hrs banging my head. Thanks to user105279's answer for hinting this.

Comment: Great catch! - I too was banging my head, since this never arose until I deployed to a different domain. (also, I had to add "return;" in the if block)

Comment: Any idea why chrome was adding the OPTIONS call? I'm having a similar issue (in Firefox).

Comment: @MegaSpaceHamlet take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. Its a CORS preflight call that browsers use to enforce CORS.

Answer (score 3):

If you have favicon on your site, remove it and try again. If your problem resolved, refactor your favicon url

Comment: This is great. I have made a request to a js file twice. Where my js file root url structure and express route url structure is same. This makes two request. Only because of this answer i have sensed

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing more or less the same thing now, and noticed the same thing.

I'm testing my server by entering the api address in chrome like this:

http://127.0.0.1:1337/links/1

my Node.js server is then responding with a json object depending on the id.

I set up a console log in the get method and noticed that when I change the id in the address bar of chrome it sends a request (before hitting enter to actually send the request) and the server accepts another request after I actually hit enter. This happens with and without having the chrome dev console open.

IE 11 doesn't seem to work in the same way but I don't have Firefox installed right now.

Hope that helps someone even if this was a kind of old thread :)

/J

Comment: On trying from firefox, its till being triggered twice. However, when I tried sending a request using POSTMAN, it was only triggered once. 

Hence I can confirm, this issue is born out of the way the browsers work.

Answer (score 2):

I am to fix with `listen.setTimeout` and `axios.defaults.timeout = 36000000`

Node js

```
var timeout = require('connect-timeout'); //express v4

//in cors putting options response code for 200 and pre flight to false
app.use(cors({ preflightContinue: false, optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));

//to put this middleaware in final of middleawares
app.use(timeout(36000000)); //10min
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   if (!req.timedout) next();
});


var listen = app.listen(3333, () => console.log('running'));
listen.setTimeout(36000000); //10min
```

React

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.timeout = 36000000;//10min
```

After of 2 days trying

Answer (score 1):

you might have to increase the timeout even more. I haven't seen the express source but it just sounds on timeout, it retries.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue doing this with Express 4. I believe it has to do with how it resolves request params. The solution is to ensure your `params` are resolved by for example checking them in an `if` block:

```
app.get('/:conversation', (req, res) => {
    let url = req.params.conversation;

    //Only handle request when params have resolved
    if (url) {
        res.redirect(301, 'http://'+ url + '.com')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you give res.send(); The axios call expects a value from the server and hence sends back a call request after 120 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my Axios POST requests were received twice by Express, the first one without body, the second one with the correct payload. The same request sent from Postman only received once correctly. It turned out that Express was run on a different port so my requests were cross origin. This caused Chrome to sent a preflight OPTION method request to the same url (the POST url) and my app.all routing in Express processed that one too.

```
app.all('/api/:cmd', require('./api.js'));
```

Separating POST from OPTIONS solved the issue:

```
app.post('/api/:cmd', require('./api.js'));
app.options('/', (req, res) => res.send());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Then I opened the Chrome dev tools and found out that the `favicon.ico` was requested from my Express.js application. I needed to fix the way how I registered the middleware.

[Screenshot of Chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S1XY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. Then I tried to add return, it didn't work. But it works when I add return res.redirect('/path');

Answer (score 0):

I also had double requests. In my case it was the forwarding from http to https protocol. You can check if that's the case by looking comparing

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']
```

It will either be 'http' or 'https'.
I could fix my issue simply by adjusting the order in which my middlewares trigger.