# Express request fires a second time

Tags: node.js, express

I'm at a little standstill here.

I'm creating an express app that have to export a huge amount of data from a Shopify store with a single request.

The issue is that when I reach the 2min mark the request is fired again ( since the default timeout is 2min ), so I increased the `server.setTimeout()` to take in consideration the time that it needs.

So this fixed the fire of the request on the 2min mark, but once my request finish, once again for some reason a second request is made.

Here is a bare bone example of the issue:

```js
const express = require('express');

function sleep(ms){
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
      setTimeout(resolve,ms)
  })
}

app.get('/export', async (req, res) => {
  // Sleep for 2:03min
  await sleep(123000);
  console.log('Starting request');
  res.status(200).send('Finish');
})

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
// Set timeout to 2:04min
server.setTimeout(124000);
```

If you open http://localhost:3000/export the result form the above code returns:

`Starting request` <- at the beginning

`Starting request` <- at the 2:04 mark

Is this some issue because of the async/await, since it seems that `res.send()` never fires ?

Can someone clarify "why" is this happening and "how" to prevent it?

**PS:** I can't use a flag or something to check if the request was already made, since the APP needs to work for users exporting the data at the same time, and the second request comes as a brand new one.

Comment: [Did you try these things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150277/express-request-is-called-twice) Also, try wrapping it in a try-catch to see if there are any silent errors due to the async function

Comment: @Fredrik S it seems that the issue there is that the request are called instantly, for me it keeps calling it without an end, so it seems that the `res.status(200).send('Finish');` is not firing at all.

Comment: In the promise constructor, why don't you have reject parameter but only resolve? and also resolve has to be called within setTimeout, not passed as function to be executed.

Comment: @Kiran Mathew Mohan the provided example is only bare bone to show the issue. There is no actual sleep in my code, but I have to make a "dummy" request for 2 min in some way. Promise allows to be resolved without reject and since resolve() is a function you can call it as a setTimeout function. You even can call it like so `Promise.resolve()` which is valid as well.

Comment: @drip for me this works just as supposed. Try disabling all extension to make sure it's not because of one of them.

Comment: @F0G and Fredrik S thanks. It seems that the issue is not present on localhost, but when I use a tunnel service like serveo.net, the problem is present. I will figure something on that end to prevent it. Thanks for the help. ( i use it for dev purposes since, I can't tie localhost as the app url for shopify :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I lost around 4 hours on this today and the conclusion is that my tunel service ( http://serveo.net/ ) was firing another request at some point perfectly timed when my export is done. ( as for why, I don't have an answer to that ) I'm still not sure if this is the correct conclusion, but switching to a different option ( or using the direct localhost ) didn't show any issues.

I moved to OpenVPN and all of my problems were gone. Ngrok was OK as well, but since the free version didn't have a fixed URL ( and it's a pain to change all of the end points in the App setup each day I start the service ) I went with OpenVPN.

The root of the problem was that `res.status(200).send('Finish')` was never firing for some specific reason or if it was it sure didn't seems so.

Thanks for all of the help.